# Oracle SQL - Find 3 Consecutive MONTH in row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to write a query to sorting out the records order by MONTH. I need to select only the 3 consecutive Month. The query should not pick values if the occurrence doesn't happen on 3 consecutive Month.

```
COLUMN ID   DATE            
100         01-MAY-2015     
100         01-JUN-2015     
100         01-JUL-2015     
100         01-AUG-2015     
111         01-MAY-2015     
111         01-JUN-2015     
111         01-AUG-2015   
111         01-SEP-2015     
122         01-APR-2015     
122         01-MAY-2015
```

OUTPUT

```
COLUMN ID   DATE            
100         01-MAY-2015     
100         01-JUN-2015     
100         01-JUL-2015
```

Any idea to execute this in Oracle SQL. Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Oracle? Different methods are available depending on the version.

Comment: Mathguy, Im using Oracle version 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is an excellent illustration of the power of the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause, introduced in Oracle 12.1.

```
with
     inputs ( id, dt ) as (
       select 100, to_date('01-MAY-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all  
       select 100, to_date('01-JUN-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 100, to_date('01-JUL-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 100, to_date('01-AUG-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 111, to_date('01-MAY-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 111, to_date('01-JUN-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 111, to_date('01-AUG-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 111, to_date('01-SEP-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 122, to_date('01-APR-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 122, to_date('01-MAY-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the SQL query)
select id, dt
from   inputs
match_recognize (
  partition by id
  order by dt
  all rows per match
  pattern ( a b b {-x*-} )
  define b as dt = add_months(prev(dt), 1)
)
;

ID   DT
---  -----------
100  01-MAY-2015
100  01-JUN-2015
100  01-JUL-2015
```

Comment: Mathguy, how if we need for 4 or more records consecutively in row?

Comment: ?? Did this work on Oracle 11g? Hard to believe! In any case: the PATTERN is `a b b {-x*}` - this means, in each partition (grouping by id), after you order by date, find any sequence of rows where the first row (`a`) is unrestricted; the second and the third row, both of class `b`, are restricted by the `define` condition; and any number of unrestricted rows (class `x`) that are not shown in the output (the `{- ... -}` notation). So if you need, say, four consecutive months, change the pattern to `a b b b {-x*-}`, for five consecutive months to `a b b b b {-x*-}`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using only analytic functions (should work in Oracle 9 and above).

NOTE: I already posted another answer, for Oracle 12.1 and above. This is a completely different approach, so it is indeed a different Answer (even if posted by the same person).

For simplicity, this query returns only the ID and **the first month** out of at least three consecutive months. As in the MATCH_RECOGNIZE solution, in this solution we also only look for the **first occurrence** of three consecutive months. (There may be five consecutive months, or three consecutive months in two different places for the same ID - we identify only the first occurrence of three consecutive months.) If all three rows - for all three months - are needed, that's easy to accommodate.

```
with
     inputs ( id, dt ) as (
       select 100, to_date('01-MAY-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all  
       select 100, to_date('01-JUN-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 100, to_date('01-JUL-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 100, to_date('01-AUG-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 111, to_date('01-MAY-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 111, to_date('01-JUN-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 111, to_date('01-AUG-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 111, to_date('01-SEP-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 122, to_date('01-APR-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 122, to_date('01-MAY-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the SQL query)
select id, min(dt) as dt
from (
       select id, dt, 
              case when lead(dt, 1) over (partition by id order by dt) = add_months(dt, 1)
                    and lead(dt, 2) over (partition by id order by dt) = add_months(dt, 2)
                   then 1 
              end as flag
       from   inputs
     )
where    flag = 1
group by id
;

 ID  DT        
---  -----------
100  01-MAY-2015
```